# How can I collapse double splat arguments into nothing?

Tags: ruby, syntax

Splat-expanding an empty array in a method call effectively reduces the argument to nothing (empty parentheses added for clarity):

```
def foo()
end

def bar(*args)
  foo(*args)
end

bar(1) # ArgumentError, as expected
bar()  # works
```

But the same does not apply to a hash argument:

```
def baz()
end

def qux(**opts)
  baz(**opts)
end

qux # ArgumentError, **opts becomes {}
```

I can work around this by explicitly checking for an empty hash:

```
def quux(callable, **opts)
  if opts.empty?
    callable.()
  else
    callable.(**opts)
  end
end

c = ->{}
quux(c) # works
```

But is there a better/nicer way to do this, or is a change to this behavior planned? I don't know the signatures of `foo` and `baz` when writing `bar` and `qux`, since the latter are part of a factory-like constructor wrapper.

Comment: Why do you need to use `**opts`? `*args` should work with keyword arguments as well.

Comment: The longer I think about it, the more I think this might actually be a bug in Ruby. If `foo(*[])` works, `baz(**{})` should work, too.

Comment: @PatrickOscity Good point with using args. Somehow forgot that. I learned the double splat syntax today and probably became a little single-minded with regards to using it. Simply using `*args` works for every case I just tried, including mixtures of optional, optional keyword, and required keyword parameters. So I don't actually need this to work now. But I still agree with your second comment, I think this is unintuitive and it might be unintentional. I'll look around for it on the bug tracker and file a report.

Comment: Scratch that, [Damien Robert beat me to it](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10708).

Comment: I think your intuition is wrong here. What would you expect `opts` hash should expand to ? Array splat operator `*` can 1:1 convert `Array` elements into *plain arguments list*, not possible and unambiguous for a `Hash`. Hash for its "expansion" needs a container object. Try `{key: 123, **opts}` and `[:key, 123, **opts]` to see what I mean.

Comment: @DavidUnric I see what you mean, but with the introduction of keyword arguments I would argue that my intuition is at least as reasonable as yours: `*[]` expands into zero positional arguments, so `**{}` should expand into zero named arguments. It arguably depends on your point of view, but in the context of a method call there are reasons to have it behave the way I expected it to work.

Comment: @Kolja I do understand your logic behind, still doubt that's a bug not an intention, partially due to compatibility with legacy code handling keyword-like arguments by a Hash parameter. Eager to see devs opinions to the above filled bugreport.

Comment: @Kolja I've put some comment to bug report #10708 and you are welcome to discuss the issue there if interested.

Comment: @DavidUnric Thanks, I just posted my opinions. Since the behavior I expected really is not necessary with what the single splat does, this comes down to a matter of taste/parser implementation. Still, I look forward to what this results in. :-)

Comment: The usual expansion container for a hash is an array of arrays.  Try `{'z'=>26,'a'=>1}.sort` to see what I mean.

Comment: The definition of `baz` is impossible as you have given it. The empty call means you have default argument so this means that calling with just `{}` is not going to break, please be more accurate of your baz definition.

Comment: @hakcho I'm not sure what you mean. Calling `base` with `**opts` will raise an ArgumentError.

Comment: `def quux(**opts)
  if opts.empty?
    baz()
  else
    baz(**opts)
  end
end` I don get the `baz` method that will work for this case but not for empty Hash.

Comment: @hakcho Yes, as written above that code, `quux` works, but is verbose.

Comment: @Kolija `baz` does not accept any arguments how can this code work?

Comment: @hakcho Oh, now I see what you mean. Sorry for being a little slow. You are right, but that's just in this example. In my real code `bar` is not known when I write `quux` (see the remark about the constructor wrapper at the end of my question). Hopefully I made the example a little clearer.

Comment: This is also confusing because I can call baz(**{}) with no problem, but it is somehow different when called from inside qux.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
def baz()
end

def qux(**opts)
    baz(*opts)
end

qux
```

To see a bit more about how *hash works try the below:

```
h = {}
puts h # {}
puts *h # nothing output 
puts **h #{}
```