# Ruby - splat and send() confusion

Tags: ruby

Ruby is telling me one argument is being passed (should be 0). I was expecting **{} to be equivalent. Where's the error in my thinking?

```
class Test
  def takenothing() end
end 

def wrapper( *args, **keys, &block )
  keys.delete :key
  Test.new.send :takenothing, *args, **keys, &block
end

wrapper key: 'nyeh'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's take a look:

```
def wrapper(*args, **keys, &block)
  keys.delete :key
  p **keys
```

OK:

```
$ ruby test.rb 
{}
```

So, no, `**{}` when calling a method does not remove it from the argument list, it just evaluates to an empty hash.

Take a look at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821422/how-can-i-collapse-double-splat-arguments-into-nothing) on StackOverflow, and the corresponding Ruby [bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10708).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is because the `send` method is calling the `takenothing` method with arguments, but the `takenothing` method does not take any arguments.

```
Test.new.send :takenothing, *args, **keys, &block
Test.new.send symbol        [, args...])
```

And your method

```
def takenothing() end  # this method takes no argument
```

Comment: Those are not just regular arguments. They're splat and kwsplat. By your logic, the method should complain about 2 arguments passed. But it says "1 passed". How so?

Comment: `*args` is optional, `**keys` allows to convert a Hash into keyword arguments. Since he only has one argument, it will be part of keys, and args will be empty. Ruby will not complain about optional arguments.

Comment: but he deletes the only key from keys.

Comment: he did, but the argument `keys` still exist as an empty hash, which counts as an argument.

Comment: But one could reason that it should be expanded into nothing, just like `*args`.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I guess Ruby doesn't operate that way.